# What is a good review article source for Physiology?

Tags: physiology, review

I am looking review articles for Physiology.
For instance, Physiological explanation of steps of measurement of the metabolism by Douglas-Haldane.

There is no section for Physiology or metabolism in Advanced Search of Nature Review.

**What is a good review article source of Physiology?**

Comment: Annual Review of Physiology? http://www.annualreviews.org/journal/physiol However the Douglas-Haldane method was published in 1913, so I'm not clear what you are hoping to find in recent reviews, but then again its really not my field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The Journal of Physiology](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/journal/10.1111/%28ISSN%291469-7793)

[Annual Reviews Physiology](http://www.annualreviews.org/journal/physiol)

[Journals from American Physiological Society](http://www.physiology.org/)

[Frontiers in Physiology](http://www.frontiersin.org/physiology)

[Experimental Physiology](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayJournal?jid=EPH)

Often, notable research papers are published in journals with high impact factors, although being published in a journal with high impact factor does not mean the research is better over research in smaller journals. But it can be a rough indication.